# I'm trying to make a show/hide style button to display in woocommerce product description for a chunk of text

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

So I am fairly new to coding in general and I am currently working on an eCommerce website to develop my skills.

Using woocommerce in WordPress, I am trying to add a 'show/hide' style button to display or hide a chunk of text using JS, but not sure where I'm going wrong. Here is my JS code which is situated in my functions.php file:

```
var i=0;
function read(){
    if(!i){
        document.getElementByID("batbut").style.display ="inline";
        document.getElementByID("read").innerHTML="Close";
        i=1;
    }
    else{
        document.getElementByID("batbut").style.display ="none";
        document.getElementByID("read").innerHTML="Battery Warning Info";
        i=0;
    }
}
```

"batbut" is the span id for the chunk of text
"read" is the button id
"read()" is the onclick attribute

the chunk of text is currently hidden using css:

```
#batbut {
    display: none;
}
```

any help would be much appreciated and if any more information is required just lmk. Thanks!

Comment: you should remove the i variable and rectify your getElementById function

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this,

check if your DOM nodes exists if yes the toggle based on the current display state of the batbut element

```
function read() {
  const elmBatbut = document.getElementById("batbut");
  const elmRead = document.getElementById("read");

  if (!elmBatbut || !elmRead) return;

  if (elmBatbut.style.display === 'none') {
    elmBatbut.style.display = "inline";
    elmRead.innerHTML = "Close";
  } else {
    elmBatbut.style.display = "none";
    elmRead.innerHTML = "Battery Warning Info";
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes the button is there but on click it does not display the hidden text. I've added your code and the problem is still there. 

This is the HTML for the button:
<button type="button" id="read" onclick="read()">Battery Warning Info</button>

Would this need to change?

Comment: I've changed this to <input type="button" onclick="runclick()" value="Battery Warning Info" /> but still the function is not being called